# Laravel 8 in ubuntu route error in production

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, routes, conflict, slug

Goodnight.

I'm having a problem with a project, which in Laragon locally works perfectly however when passing to the server the error. The error is confusion with 3 routes, which when I try to access them (Login, Register, Logout), Laravel assumes that they are other category search routes, giving an error for not finding them. The strangest thing is that it works locally.

Here are some data:

Laravel Version: 8. Php Version: 8.0.3

Routes which include those that give an error (only login and register, the others work):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {
    // Authentication Routes
    Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');
    Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login.post');
    // Socialite Routes
    Route::get('login/{provider}', [SocialLoginController::class, 'login'])->name('social.login');
    Route::get('login/{provider}/callback', [SocialLoginController::class, 'login']);
    // Registration Routes
    Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'showRegistrationForm'])->name('register');
    Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register'])->name('register.post');
    // Confirm Account Routes
    Route::get('account/confirm/{token}', [ConfirmAccountController::class, 'confirm'])->name('account.confirm');
    Route::get('account/confirm/resend/{uuid}', [ConfirmAccountController::class, 'sendConfirmationEmail'])->name('account.confirm.resend');
    // Password Reset Routes
    Route::get('password/reset', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'showLinkRequestForm'])->name('password.email');
    Route::post('password/email', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'sendResetLinkEmail'])->name('password.email.post');
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', [ResetPasswordController::class, 'showResetForm'])->name('password.reset.form');
    Route::post('password/reset', [ResetPasswordController::class, 'reset'])->name('password.reset');
});
```

More routes that work well, and the category routes it goes to when I try to login or register (assumes Login, register or Logout is a category):

```
Route::get('propertie/details/{id}','HomeController@details');
Route::post('inquery','HomeController@inqueryDetails')->name('inquery');
Route::get('inquery_list','HomeController@inqueryShow')->name('inquery_show');
Route::get('my-product','HomeController@myproduct');
Route::get('categorydata','HomeController@categoryData');
Route::get('categorydatacat2','HomeController@categoryDataCat2');
Route::get('categorydatacat3','HomeController@categoryDataCat3');
Route::get('categorydatacat4','HomeController@categoryDataCat4');
Route::get('getModels','HomeController@getModels');
Route::get('saveLog','HomeController@saveLog');
Route::get('about','HomeController@about');
Route::get('search','HomeController@search');
Route::get('faq','HomeController@faqs')->name('faq');
Route::get('activeNews','HomeController@news')->name('activeNews');

Route::get('contact', [ContactController::class, 'index'])->name('contact');
Route::post('contact/submit', [ContactController::class, 'create'])->name('contact.submit');
Route::post('/news_letter/', [ContactController::class, 'newsLetter']);
Route::post('contact/send', [ContactController::class, 'send'])->name('contact.send');
Route::get('/upgrade_plan','Plan\PlanController@index')->name('plan.index');

Route::get('/news_page','News\NewsController@index')->name('news.index');
Route::get('/news_page/{id}','News\NewsController@show')->name('news.show');

// Report Route
Route::get('/report','Report\ReportController@index')->name('report.index');
Route::post('/report_search','Report\ReportController@filterReport');

//Paypal
Route::get('paypal/success','PaymentController@paymentInfo');
Route::get('payment/cancel', function () {
   return 'Payment has been canceled';
});

/*
 * These frontend controllers require the user to be logged in
 * All route names are prefixed with 'frontend.'
 * These routes can not be hit if the password is expired
 */
//plan module
Route::get('/upgrade_plan','Plan\PlanController@index')->name('plan.index');
Route::get('planlist','Plan\PlanController@planList')->name('planlist.index');
Route::post('planselect','Plan\PlanController@planSelect');
Route::get('payment_setting/{id}','Plan\PlanController@paymentSetting');
Route::post('paymentstore','Plan\PlanController@paymentStore');

Route::get('pages/{slug}','HomeController@staticsPages');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'password_expires']], function () 
{
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'User', 'as' => 'user.'], function () {
        // User Dashboard Specific
        Route::get('dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');

        // User Account Specific
        Route::get('account', [AccountController::class, 'index'])->name('account');

        Route::get('products','ProductController@productList')->name('products');
        Route::view('/address', 'frontend.user.address')->name('address');
        Route::view('/payment_setting', 'frontend.user.payment_setting')->name('payment_setting');
        Route::get('add-product/pick-a-category','ProductController@addProduct');
        Route::get('add-product/taxonomy/{slug}','ProductController@categoryName');
        Route::get('add-product/{slug}/{id}/category','ProductController@productCategory');
        Route::get('add-products','ProductController@addProducts');
        Route::post('addproduct','ProductController@addProductStore')->name('addproduct');
        Route::get('product/edit/{id}','ProductController@editProduct');
        Route::post('product/update/{id}', 'ProductController@updateProduct');
        Route::get('product/delete/{id}', 'ProductController@deleteProduct');
        Route::get('product/status/{id}', 'ProductController@productStatus');
       Route::get('categoryfield', 'ProductController@getCategorycustomfield')->name('categoryfield');
       Route::get('brandmodel', 'ProductController@brandModelGet')->name('brandmodel');
       Route::get('searchajax', 'ProductController@autoComplete')->name('searchajax');
       Route::post('imagecompress', 'ProductController@imageUpload');
       Route::post('review-rate', 'ProductController@rateReview');
       Route::get('getLeadTracker','DashboardController@getLeadTracker')->name('getLeadTracker');
      
        // User Profile Specific
        Route::patch('profile/update', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    });
});
Route::get('{slug}','HomeController@allServices');
Route::get('product/service','HomeController@productServices');
Route::post('trackSellerProfile','HomeController@trackSellerProfile');
```

Follow the .htacess, as I also saw somewhere that the error could be here:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Additional information:
-The routing system is divided into several files.

- Error is with route Route::get('{slug}','HomeController@allServices');
- Only occurs with AuthController routes (login, register, logout), with the others it works.
- All routes appear in `route:list`, with the slug being the last one.
- If I disable the slug route, the routes are accessible.
- Locally everything works perfectly, being exactly the same project

Thanks for all the help in advance and I apologize for any mistakes I might make as I'm new to StackOverflow.

Best regards

Comment: On production, routing must somehow skip the middleware guest group. Not sure why. Replace 'guest' with 'web' and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you comment @DimitriMostrey.  I tried to change it, make the php artisan optimize and it remains the same. This error also happens in the case of logout, which is outside this middleware group.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
I recommend reading [How to create a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)